# Generate scaffold in admin section spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

How to generate a scaffold in admin section of spree app. I tried using spree_scaffold but its not working

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'spree', '3.0.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this command.

```
rails g scaffold Spree::Admin::Blog title:string
```